# Why does my VB.NET array have extra values?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, off-by-one

I declare my array

```
Dim A(N) As Integer
```

When I loop from `1 To N` or `0 To N-1` there's an extra value at one end or the other.

What's going on?

<sub>(Intended to be a canonical question/answer.)</sub>

Comment: You will get the reasoning behind that in this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/506207/size-of-array-in-visual-basic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In VB.NET arrays almost always* have a lower bound of `0` and are declared mentioning their upper bound, not their length.

They did change the VB.NET syntax early on to allow you to remind yourself if needed:

```
Dim A(0 To N) As Integer
```

That `0` can't be anything else (such as a `1` or a constant zero).

You can loop through all VB.NET array indexes using

```
For i = LBound(A) To UBound(A)
```

or, more simply,

```
For i = 0 To N
```

(*) You can use the .NET Framework to create arrays with other lower bounds, but you need to refer to them as `Array` and thus with late binding (and probably `Option Strict Off`).

Comment: It's not strictly true that arrays in VB.Net always have a lower bound of zero, see this overload of [`Array.CreateInstance`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x836773a.aspx). It's just that anyone found writing such code should never be allowed near computers again.