# Getting "Index is outside bounds of array" error but there is data inside the location

Tags: vb.net

I am getting an Indexing error on my code but I am very sure that there is data inside the location I am trying to print.

Below is the problem code.

```
Private Sub ComboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox2.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim seriesName As String = ComboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString()
    Dim seriesLocation As String = "excelFiles/seriesID.csv"
    Dim seriesData = File.ReadAllText(seriesLocation)
    Dim seriesRows = Split(seriesData, vbCrLf)
    For Each line In seriesRows
        Dim seriesItem = Split(line, ",")
        If seriesItem(1) = seriesName Then '<--- this is the error line
            TextBox2.Text += seriesItem(2) + ","
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

I have used this code in a similar sub which works, and have accessed the file in an another but I just can not understand why this isn't working on this one.

I am trying to use the item inside a combo-box and compare it to data from a CSV stored in an array.

I have added some pictures below showing the error and what happens when I try to display the location.

[Error when running normally](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BmMTH.png)

[Difference in Printing Location "0" (top) and "1" (bottom)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EHWVw.png)

The only difference is that I have changed seriesItem(1) to seriesItem(0)

Thanks for your help

Comment: `If line.Contains(",") Then`  Your image even shows that line = "".  So, no comma.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does my VB.NET array have extra values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29840510/why-does-my-vb-net-array-have-extra-values)

Comment: Your file location probably isn't where you think it is.  Use a full path.

Comment: @LarsTech I have used that path twice before in the program and they work fine. The problem is in the for loop, I tried JaydipJ solution and while it worked it wasn't comparing the right location in the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So upon working with the program and the CSV, it seems that the program will only compare something if it is located in location 0. When I moved things around in the CSV I managed to get the program working.

As the problem has now become something else I am going to close this question and post a new one.

Thank you all for replying and offering your help.